# Text Field returns nil when there's a space

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, alamofire, swifty-json

If someone can help me understand/fix why it keeps crashing/saying my results is nil when there's an actual string being sent.

I know the problem has to do with white space but what am I doing wrong?

- When I type "Hello", it works fine.
- When I type "Hello Word", the error appears and says it's nil.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

@IBAction func searchBtn(sender: UIButton) {
  let searchTerm:String = self.searchTextField.text!
  let apiUrl = "http://localhost/v1/define?term=\(searchTerm)" 

  Alamofire.request(.GET, apiUrl!).responseJSON { response in print(response)
    let jsonData = JSON(response.result.value!)
    if jsonData["result_type"] == "exact" {
      let definitionText = jsonData["list"][0]["definition"].string
      self.resultLabel.text = definitionText
    } else {
      self.resultLabel.text = "Sorry, your word does not have a definition."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What line of code is producing the error? (If the app stops in the debugger, one of the lines should be highlighted.)

Comment: You need to add percentage escape

Comment: You cant straight use normal text when use it for URL, have to encode it according to your server first, most is using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding `

Comment: I think API doesn't return any content for "Hello World" text.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I created an encoded variable but it still returns nil. What am I doing wrong?

let encodeSearchTerm = searchTerm.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())

Comment: @Tj3n Thanks. That makes sense. Can you give me an example of how to use that? The one you suggested seems to have deprecated in Swift 2.

Comment: @Michael "Hello World !!!".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters( .URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet() )   //  "Hello%20World%20!!!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this for URL encode in swift 2, hope it work

```
let escapedSearchText = searchText.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet())!
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like a charm! Why doesn't NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet() work as advertise?

Comment: I tried with `NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet() ` and it also work for me :O i use that `letterCharacterSet ` only for encode search text, but both result same string

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this method: [stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:)

```
var searchTerm:String = self.searchTextField.text!
searchTerm = searchTerm.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!
let apiUrl = "http://localhost/v1/define?term=\(searchTerm)"
```